# Random Integer Array from positive integer array

Tags: arrays, random, integer

I have an array of positive integers, what are some tricks to turn that array into one with negative numbers too?
For example one could be

```
r * (b-a) + a with b = -1 and a = 1
```

Do you know any other tricks like this?

Comment: `array[0] = -1;`

Comment: How many negative numbers do you want? What is the range of the ints or an expected output? Otherwise just add `array[0] = -1;` as suggested and you have your negative number.

Comment: Random number of negative numbers